# Yjra eror search datatable zero-length delimited identifier at or near

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, yajra-datatable

`Exception Message:\n\nSQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near \"\"\"\"\nLINE 1: ... aggregate from \"bloks\" where (LOWER(CAST(\"bloks\".\"\" as TEXT...\n`

I always get this error when I search using the Yajra package, can someone help me with my solution

next code

```
$data = Blok::select();                            

return Datatables::of($data)
    ->addIndexColumn()
    ->addColumn('action', function ($data) use ($hasManageUser) {
        $output = '';
        if ($data->name == 'Super Admin') {
            return '';
        }
        if ($hasManageUser) {
            $output = '<div class="table-actions">
                    <a href="' . url('blok/' . $data->id_blok) . '" ><i class="ik ik-edit-2 f-16 mr-15 text-green"></i></a>
                    <a href="' . url('blok/delete/' . $data->id_blok) . '"><i class="ik ik-trash-2 f-16 text-red"></i></a>
                </div>';
        }

        return $output;
    })
    ->rawColumns(['action'])
    ->make(true);
```

and model code

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Blok extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'bloks';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_blok';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_afdelling',
        'blok',
        'gisafdelling_id',
        'alias',
        'gisblok_id',
    ];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please cut and paste the text from your screenshot, super-accurately, into your question by [edit]ing it. The arrangement of quote marks likely holds the answer to your question, or at least a step on the path to an answer.

Comment: Check your laravel.log and copy/paste entire stacktrace in original question. Where did that query come from? Which controller? Which relation?